# Question about multiplying a rank $1$ density matrix with a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, trace

Let $\rho$ be a density matrix (positive semidefinite and trace $1$), with its rank being $1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\rho = v v^{*},
\end{equation}
where $v$ is a $n \times 1$ unit vector.

Let $M$ be a positive semidefinite matrix such that all its eigenvalues are between $0$ and $1$.

I am trying to see whether the following two inequalities are correct:
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}\left(M^{2} \rho\right)  \leq \text{Tr}\left(M \rho\right).
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|| M v|| \leq \text{Tr}\left(M \rho\right),
\end{equation}
where $||\cdot||$ is the $2$-norm of a vector.

---

The statement is obviously true when $M$ is a projector. But what about more general $M$? Note that if the first inequality is true, it implies the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the eigendecomposition $M= P\Lambda P'$.  Since $$\mathrm{trace}(M^2\rho) = \mathrm{trace}(v^*M^2v) = v^*M^2v$$ and $$\mathrm{trace}(M\rho) = v^*Mv,$$ we have that $$v^*(M - M^2)v = v^*(P\Lambda P' - P\Lambda^2 P')v = v^*P(\Lambda - \Lambda^2)P'v\geq 0$$ as the difference $\Lambda-\Lambda^2$ is positive semidefinite (because the eigenvalues are bounded by 0 from below and by 1 from above).

Note that your assumptions on $v$ are not necessary.